# Converting Web Service DateTime string to MM/dd/yyyy format in MVC application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

In my MVC Form

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.achPayDate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-7" })
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.achPayDate)                                        
</div>
```

In my Model

```
[DisplayName("Payment Date")]
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
public string achPayDate { get; set; }
```

`achPayDate` is getting data from the web service

```
achPayDate = 2016-09-21T00:00:00-07:00
```

And I wanted to format that to MM/dd/yyyy  so it is 09/21/2016.  I tried

```
[DisplayName("Payment Date")]
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString=("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}"))]
public string achPayDate { get; set; }
```

which is not working. I also tried

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.achPayDate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-7" })
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.achPayDate, "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")                                        
</div>
```

which is not working

Not sure what should I do

Comment: Why are you using **string** type for a achPayDate ? Use `DateTime`. The code you shown in the question does not show how you are reading the value from the web service result and mapping to the property of your view model. Any way, take a look at `DateTime.ParseExact` documentation.

Comment: Your property is typeof `string`. It needs to be `DateTime` -  `public DateTime achPayDate { get; set; }` in order to use format strings (and `[DataType(DataType.Date)]` is only applicable when using `@Html.EditorFor()`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer myself!  Here is what I did

in the Model

```
    [DisplayName("Payment Date")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime? achPayDate { get; set; }
```

and in the MVC form

```
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.achPayDate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-7" })
                                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.achPayDate, new {@class="date"})                                        
                                </div>
```